# Графики загружености WMware vs zabbix

Tags: виртуальная-машина, zabbix

Есть два мониторинга виртуальной машины один от `WMware`,  другой от `zabbix_agent`, периодически разнятся, вопрос кому больше верить ?

Comment: а в каких показателях разнятся??

Comment: Zabbix конечно!

Comment: в показателях  cpu  lan mem

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от частоты опроса, я думаю показатели в VMWare более корректны.